# Pygame support on m1 macs

Tags: python, macos, pygame, apple-m1

Does pygame work on M1 macs? It isn't working on mine, it only shows up with a white screen. Does this happen on other people's M1 mac's or does it happen with python 3.7? It's really annoying because I just finished all the sprites for my first game and I don't have anything to work with.